# TMS320C6713 has problems with interrupt timing?

Tags: interrupt-handling, code-composer, ti-dsp

Im working with CCS5v5 on Win7, DSK6713.

I have tow different c Files and one header(white_noise.h).

There are two different scenarios

1. I can build and debug, and it works-> with adding the header white_noise.h and with N=128(in NLMS.c, Filter coefficients)
2. I can build and debug, and it doesnt do what it should do by -> adding the header white_noise.h and with N=256 (in NLMS.c, Filter coefficients)

Idk Why ? I dont use the header(white_noise.h). I guess there is a time problem with the interrupt?

Thank you so much for reading!
regards 
Daniel

---

```
     white_noise.h
    short IR[8000]={23670, -2424, -25025, 23474, 32467, -10922, -5724,....
```

---

```
NLMS.c
//Optimization Level 2

#include "refnoise.h"           //cosine 312 Hz
#include "dplusn.h"             //sin(1500) + sin(312)


//#define mue 1E-10             //rate of convergence
#define N 128                   //# of weights (coefficients)
#define NS 128                  //# of output sample points
#define delta 1E-10
#define alpha 1E-3
float w[N];                     //buffer weights of adapt filter
float delay[N];                 //input buffer to adapt filter,x
short output;                   //overall output
float yn, E;                    //output filter/"error" signal

float gamma=0.01;
float Px=4500.0;
float mue = 1E-10;              //rate of convergence
float mue2;
short input_option=1;

  short NLMS_function()
{
      static short buffercount=0;       //init count of # out samples

          delay[0] = refnoise[buffercount];  //cos(312Hz) input to adapt FIR

      Px= (1.0-gamma)*Px + gamma*delay[0]*delay[0];

        short i;
         yn = 0;                            //init output of adapt filter
         for (i = 0; i < N; i++)            //to calculate out of adapt FIR
         {
             yn += (w[i] * delay[i]);       //output of adaptive filter
             //Px= (1-gamma)*Px + gamma*delay[i]*delay[i];
         }

         E = dplusn[buffercount] - yn;      //"error" signal=(d+n)-yn

         mue= 0.01/(Px*N+delta);
         for (i = N-1; i >= 0; i--)         //to update weights and delays
           {
             w[i] = w[i] + mue*E*delay[i]; //update weights
             delay[i] = delay[i-1];         //update delay samples
           }


         buffercount++;                     //increment buffer count
         if (buffercount >= NS)           //if buffercount=# out samples
             buffercount = 0;               //reinit count


         output = ((short)E*10);        //"error" signal overall output


         return output;                 //return from ISR
}
```

---

main.c

```
#include "DSK6713_AIC23.h"
//#include "white_noise.h"
short NLMS_function();
Uint32 fs= DSK6713_AIC23_FREQ_8KHZ;

//Define
#define LEFT 0                      //stereo
#define RIGHT 1                     //stereo

short input;

interrupt void c_int11()        //ISR
{
    DSK6713_LED_on(0);


    output=NLMS_function();
     output_sample(output);             //overall output result


     DSK6713_LED_off(0);
     return;                    //return from ISR
}

main()
{
    DSK6713_LED_init();                         //init LEDs

     short T=0;
     for (T = 0; T < 30; T++)
       {
         w[T] = 0;                //init buffer for weights
         delay[T] = 0;            //init buffer for delay samples
       }
     comm_intr();                       //init DSK, codec, McBSP
     while(1);                          //infinite loop                                     //infinite loop
}
```